# Two Apps in iPad side-by-side i.e. sharing screen between two apps?

Tags: ipad

I would like to have PDF Expert -app and UPAd -note-atking-app at the same time open where 50% screen area preserved for each. Is it possible to share the screen this way? This way studying would be more natural: I have lecture-slides open and a note-book, not all the time going to-and-fro. Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. Only one application can use the screen at a time.

Comment: ...this is not possible because iPad has no multitasking or way?

Comment: At this time, it is simply a feature that the iPad does not offer. I believe that it is technically possible, but would require user interface modification and developer participation.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to split your screen, but you might try an app like [notability](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/notability-take-notes-annotate/id360593530?mt=8) or [good notes](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/goodnotes-notes-pdf/id424587621?mt=8), which allow you to read PDF's and take notes at the same time.